# Non-Play Store emulator: How to resolve "serial console enabled, performance impacted. visit bootloader to resolve" in Android studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]To moderators: I have searched through other answers, but I could not find a suitable solution for most people like me who are not good at creating a kernel. I am looking for an answer that does not require creating a new kernel from scratch.

reference image: